How child process works in node.js?
We know that js or nodeJs is single threaded, but we can work with child process.
My question is how child process works if nodejs is single threaded?
Can anyone explain? please...

There are ways to use multithreading (to a limited extend) in NodeJS, have a look at worker threads.

But besides, just launching two or more separate NodeJS programs (possibly a main program launching child ones) achieves multithreading by providing multiple processes.

In this context, what "child process" are you referring to? If it's this one this just starts an entirely new process

Yes, I am talking about this. one you mentioned. thanks @derpirscher

Yes, Node.js is single-threaded in terms of its event loop, meaning it uses a single thread to execute JavaScript code.
The core of Node.js is based on JavaScript's event-driven, non-blocking architecture. The event loop operates on a single thread, which means it handles I/O tasks like file reading, database queries, and HTTP requests asynchronously. But the actual execution of JavaScript code is done in one thread.

What is a Child Process?

"As far as I know, I could be wrong. Please correct me if I am."
A child process in Node.js refers to a completely independent instance of the Node.js runtime. You can create child processes to run tasks in parallel with the main event loop. Even though Node.js itself is single-threaded, you can spawn separate processes that run in parallel, allowing the system to perform multi-threaded operations at the operating system level.

How Child Processes Work in Node.js:

When you use the child process module in Node.js, it spins up a separate process that runs independently of the main thread. These child processes do not share the same memory space with the main process, which makes them different from threads (which share memory). Communication between the main process and child processes happens via inter-process communication (IPC), typically using messaging
